# Regex to do a file path for runtime exec java

Tags: java, regex

More of a question of is this something that is possible, I suspect that it is. I have an application deployed on tomcat and from the java code I would like to reference some python code. I am able to do this with runtime exec, with a hardcoded path to my webapps folder where I have also put in the python code.

```
String pythonEntry = "C:\\apps\\tomcat\\webapps\\app_name##_version\\WEB-INF\\app-python\\my_python_file.py"
```

However, my issue with hardcoding this path is that the "##_version" will change every time there is a new version. Can I make this dynamic with a regex so that it just finds the folder that is "app_name" without caring about what is in "##version"?

Or is that the wrong approach entirely?

Comment: Can't you just set the path in a config file?

Comment: What is the desired behavior if there are multiple versions in that folder?

Comment: What do the `##` mean in the path?  Do you literally have pound signs?  If not, can you show some sample data?

Comment: @SystemGlitch yeah I can just set it in a properties file, but then I need to change it very frequently, which I want to avoid, I just want it to go to whatever path contains app_name##whatever.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the ## allows tomcat to ignore this part of the folder name. The path does actually contain the ## signs. So app_name##_version keeps my url as "whatever.com/app_name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a JavaEE web app running in Tomcat.

Then you should use a servlet-context-relative path (i.e. start from `/WEB-INF`).

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/app-python/my_python_file.py");
```

Where `request` is `HttpServletRequest`.

More info can be found here: [`ServletContext.getRealPath(java.lang.String)`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))